# How to combine two or more p2 repositories

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have generated a P2 Repo using my own components and features.. I have generated another Repo using another components and features

Is it possible to merge these two repositories using any tool?

I will appreciate,can anyone help me on this please

Comment: Why do you want to merge the two p2-repos? With WSO2 Carbon, you can add several p2-repos under the Feature Management. Then, you can install the features from the both p2-repos. https://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon420/Installing+Features+via+the+UI

Comment: @KasunBG Thanks for your response.. I don't want to add using WSO2 ui.. IS any other method to do this? That's what i asked...Or is there any way to install features/products into Carbon instance without using UI?? Please help me on this...

Comment: It's possible to install features via command-line. Start the wso2 server with osgi console `bin/wso2server.{sh,bat} -DosgiConsole`.  See the user guide here - http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Console_Users_Guide

Comment: I guess you will need the `provaddrepo` osgi command, and `provinstall`

Comment: @KasunBG Thanks for your response.. will go thru that...pls have a look in to this,i have tried using Carbon P2 Plugin to install features into carbon instance,but facing issue,,Have u tried this before?? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/22711422/2822914)

Comment: @KasunBG I have tried what u have shared the Information, FOr eg i want to install Student management feature in wso2 carbon. I have started the wso2 server with osgi bundle . I have this feature in my system (Say eg c://p2-repo). How to install this feature in carbon

i tried as u sai **provinstall org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.feature.group 4.2.0** but getting error as `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Installable unit not found: org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.feature.group 4.2.0` Obviuoslye,so where i mentioned my repo,that feature is there in side my repo??

Comment: I haven't tried to install features via the osgi console, but it should be possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by platform.xml. But here is a sample pom I have used before to install features via Carbon P2 plugin - http://blog.kasunbg.org/2014/02/merge-wso2-carbon-products-using-maven.html

Comment: @KasunBG Can you help me to install features using OSGI Console.Can you tried and help me on this,my requirement is need to install the features on carbon without using UI. Any other options are there,in the meantime i ll look on your blog and will try that